# Can i do this with forms in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

I am trying to write this, but it doesn't seem to work. Please help me.

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <script> 
      function myFunction(){
          alert("Hello there!");
      }
      document.forms[0].setAttribute("onsubmit", "return myFunction();"); 
  </script>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: why not directly write your function name for submit event. What are you trying to do exactly.

Comment: You're putting the `<script>` insdie the `<form>`. 
You should first of all put it outside. second, set the callback function on the `onsubmit` and trigger that with an eventlistener

Comment: you can change `<script>` to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: the idea is that someone clicks the submit button, it takes them to another page. but before the page, an alert pops up.

Comment: @Akhilesh: the `type` attribute is not needed anymore, hasn't been for many years. MDN: "The HTML5 specification urges authors to omit the attribute rather than provide a redundant MIME type" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: changing <script> to <script type="text/javascript"> does not seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the script tag with your JavaScript code *outside* your form tags, and actually return something from the submit handler function, then it works:

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script> 
  function myFunction(){
alert("Hello there!");
return true;
  }
  document.forms[0].setAttribute("onsubmit", "return myFunction()"); 
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].onsubmit = function(){}` will also work